# For Loop doesn't loop Buttons array to make them invisible it only hide the first one on the list - Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my app, there are many buttons that I want to make invisible while the app display queries result. Following sample code on this site, I coded my test app and was unable to make the loop run through the array, instead it only pick on the first item and then stopped. what is wrong?

Here is my sample code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       
        Button btn03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button btn04 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button btn05 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

        Button[] buttonArray = {btn05, btn04, btn03};

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mytextsize, android.R.id.text1, kakNmbrs);

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button3:
                bUttn = "3";
                break;

            case R.id.button4:
                break;

            case R.id.button5:
                if (bUttn.equals("3")) {
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    for (int i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) {
                        Button thisButton = buttonArray[i];
                       thisButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your loop is within only one case of the switch statement, maybe thats the issue

Comment: Try removing the "break" from inside the loop :)

Comment: Yup, that worked, thank you Sagan